# R Try reading a csv and if it doesn't exist read a different one

Tags: r

I have a script where I'd prefer to read in a certain file, but if that file doesn't exist then I want to read in a different file. Files change by day so I don't want to pick and choose manually.

I'm currently using `tryCatch` to do this. Basically, try to read the first file, and if there's an error then return an empty df. Then have logic where if the table is blank, read in the file I know exists. While my solution works, it feels extremely clunky and I'd like to learn best practices going forward.

Current solution:

```
df <- suppressWarnings(tryCatch({read.csv('this file will not exist on your computer', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)},
                                             error = function(e) data.frame()
      ))

if(nrow(df) == 0){
  df <- cars # this will be a file I know exists
}

## Continue with function using a df I know exists ##
```

I don't love using `suppressWarnings` if I don't need to, but I disliked the warning that kept popping up (obviously the file doesn't exist that's why I'm tryCatching).

Ideally this could be a 3-line code. 1) Check if file exists. 2) If it does exist then read it. 3) If it doesn't exist, then read the other file I know exists. Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the `file.exists` function [(link)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @All Downhill From Here using `file.exists` would check if the file exists at the given location. As `file.exists` returns a logical value you can wrap it in `if`/`else` block.

```
if(file.exists('data.csv')) {
  data <- read.csv('data.csv')
} else {
  data <- read.csv('confirm.csv')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This also could be an option using `purrr::map_if`. First we create a character vector of our desired file names:

```
library(purrr)

vec <- c("data.csv")

vec %>% 
  map_if(~ file.exists(.x), ~ read.csv(.x, header = TRUE), 
         .else = read.csv(gsub("([a-z0-9_]+)\\.([a-z]+$)", "confirm\\.\\2", 
                                 vec, perl = TRUE), header = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may make use of an index

```
data <- read.csv(c("confirm.csv", "data.csv")[1 + file.exists("data.csv")])
```